# Is "How much he'll be happy" correct?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Is it correct the following:

> I don't know how much he will be happy about it.

Comment: You might be interested in the community for [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is,

> I don't know how happy he will be about it.